# How to convert javascript to Winjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, winjs

I am new to WinJS application. I can find many sources for html5, javascript and css. If I want to execute them in my WinJS application, what is the process? Is it necessary to change the entire code in WinJS? It seems like little complicated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A Windows 8 HTML5/JavaScript application is exactly that HTML5 and JavaScript and you can (but don't have to) use the WinJS libraries.  They do give you a richer native experience and awareness of the Windows 8 navigation model, but it's possible to pull in other libraries like jQuery, jQUeryUI, Knockout.js, Angular, etc. too.

Windows 8 HTML5/JavaScript applications are sandboxed so some libraries may break the [rules for the specific context the app is running in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx), in which case you may need to make modifications and adjustments (e.g, [what jQueryGeo did to adapt](http://www.sitepoint.com/windows-8-jquery-geo-and-tostatichtml/))

I'd recommend doing a little exploration of the [HTML5/JavaScript samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps) and working through the [App Builder program/curriculum](http://build.windowsstore.com/build-windows-store-apps-using-web-technologies/#fbid=bDgnuNA0Vwj) that's targeted for HTML/JavaScript developers for more insight.

If you have a specific application/code you're looking to bring into Windows 8, create a new basic app, pull in the assets, and set the start page in the Visual Studio project's manifest;  I suspect you'll have a relatively functional app that you can then tweak/build on.

Comment: and expect the 'use strict' option thats there by default to introduce some issues because of loose programming practices for those that dont use strict mode :)

Comment: PS my first 'WinJS' app (although it was pure html/js without the use of the WinJS lib) I took some really cool complex javascript demos and css3 advanced demos, put them into a Win8 app with a few minor tweaks to run them all at one and voila - it worked well - animations and all.